# Group two(2) or more categorical data by week(7days) in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

This is how my data looks like:

I want to aggregate this by category, Issue and Date(weekly) to get count of record.

Date: Group, the result should be monday to sunday

Count: ADD, if two or more records have same Name and fall in a same week Date time (if falls on same interval 7 days week)

The desired output is given below:

[image: original data]

| Category | Issue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bakes | Back Brake failures | 11/28/2022 |
| Machines | Oiling of the machines | 11/29/2022 |
| Cars | windscreen broken | 11/30/2022 |
| Cars | steering wheel is shaking | 11/30/2022 |
| Bakes | The tyres are flat | 12/01/2022 |
| Machines | Normal wear and tear | 12/02/2022 |
| Machines | Normal wear and tear | 12/02/2022 |
| Cars | warning lights are on | 12/03/2022 |
| Bakes | Back Brake failures | 12/04/2022 |
| Machines | Oiling of the machines | 12/05/2022 |
| Cars | windscreen broken | 12/06/2022 |
| Bakes | excessive emissions | 12/06/2022 |
| Bakes | The tyres are flat | 12/07/2022 |
| Machines | Normal wear and tear | 12/08/2022 |
| Cars | warning lights are on | 12/09/2022 |
| Bakes | Brake pads worn | 12/10/2022 |
| Machines | Machine is consuming too much oil | 12/11/2022 |
| Cars | the tyres are wearing unevenly | 12/11/2022 |

I want to have a result similar to this:

[image: required solution]

if possible the count should be sorted in descending order

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you should provide a fully reproducible input (images are not)

Comment: amendment done to the input

Comment: @mozway, can I please get a helping hand. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with a weekly period:

```
pd.crosstab([df['Category'], df['Issue']],
            pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W'),
            margins=True, margins_name='Grand Total'
           )
```

Output:

```
Date                                           2022-11-28/2022-12-04  2022-12-05/2022-12-11  Grand Total
Category    Issue                                                                                       
Bakes       Back Brake failures                                    2                      0            2
            Brake pads worn                                        0                      1            1
            The tyres are flat                                     1                      1            2
            excessive emissions                                    0                      1            1
Cars        steering wheel is shaking                              1                      0            1
            the tyres are wearing unevenly                         0                      1            1
            warning lights are on                                  1                      1            2
            windscreen broken                                      1                      1            2
Machines    Machine is consuming too much oil                      0                      1            1
            Normal wear and tear                                   2                      1            3
            Oiling of the machines                                 1                      1            2
Grand Total                                                        9                      9           18
```